# WordPress Можно ли создать выбор изображений только из определенной директории?

Tags: wordpress

Опишу проблему. Есть сайт на WP где у пользователей есть возможность при создании поста назначать для какого-то элемента изображение. Как сделать так, что б в этом конкретном случаии можно б было только выбрать изображения, скажем из папки `uploads/test/*` из тех которые были загружены в данную папку админом. А админ имел бы возможность добавлять через `Media Library` именно в эту папку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я знаю, именно сюда это добавить нельзя. К тому же, это не имеет отношения к физическим директориям на диске. Обычно если есть необходимость в реализации неких "директорий", то это реализуется посредством таксономий для пост тайпа attachment.

Comment: ок, а есть способ, сделать что б в `guid` для таких "постов" был доступ только к конкретной папке ?

Comment: Типа как фильтровать их? Есть минимум несколько бесплатных плагинов: [певрый](https://wordpress.org/plugins/filebird/), [второй](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/), [третий](https://wordpress.org/plugins/folders/), -- и премиальные тоже есть, например [Folders](https://premio.io/downloads/folders/). Самостоятельная реализация потребует определенных усилий, само собой.

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Установил, опробовал. Интересно как оно их перепривязывает по фильтрам ? Я посмотрел что данние плагины не создают новых дерикторий в `uploads/test/*`  Они как-то наздачают, что данные медиафайлы теперь принадлежат выбраной категории.

Comment: Да, как я и писал выше, все это работает посредством создания таксономий. А на счет перепривязки, возможно не совсем Вас понял.

Comment: Вот в таблице wp_post есть информация о медиафайле, предположим `uploads/2024/test.svg` После установки плагина, этот файл и другие, которых я захотел как-то определить в "категорию" предположим t-shirts переопределились. Но вот я не понимаю как WP их вяжет? Думал что-то в wp_postmeta для данных файлов добавляет, но  - нет. Предположим Мне понадобиться вызвать с базы данных все эти изображения установленые в t-shirts куда смотреть ?

Comment: Вяжет по taxonomy term, все эти папки они виртуальные, грубо говоря, не буду утвреждать прямо за все плагины, но обычно просто для post type attachment, регистрируется таксономия, по типу forlder, и все. Когда-то доводилось такую коммерцию делать.

Comment: Спасибо, наконец дошло... оно создает в `wp_term_taxonomy` новую таксономию, а уже в `wp_term_relationships` вяжет это все в виртуальные связки.  Совершенно не понятно зачем было так усложнять, почему для этих действий нельзя было в wp_post отдельную колонку предусмотреть. Зачем разработчики WP пошли таким путем... хотя может так быстрее выборка

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал что это усложнение, а скорее выход из ситуации. Так как это не то чтобы дефолтный функционал.